# How to create a screenshot taking application using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, screenshot

I am thinking of making a Screenshot application using Flutter.

The features of the screenshot application will be:

- Creating a floating button, that can float/draw over other apps. The button is should be draggable too.
- Taking screenshot of the whole screen, when the user presses the floating button.
- Storing the screenshots in the local storage.

[Like this floating button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx1QY.jpg) And when I click that floating button, it should take a screenshot of the whole screen.

Is there any widget or package available for this purpose?
Any suggestions for implementing this approach are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: how did you solve this ? i cant found anything about it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an plugin ([screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)) which allows you to capture widgets as Images. So you can also capture the widgets that are not rendered on the screen.

Step 1:

```
  //Create an instance of ScreenshotController
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
```

Step 2:
Wrap the widget that you want to capture inside Screenshot

```
Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Text("This text will be captured as image"),
),
```

Step 3:
Take the screenshot by calling capture method. This will return a Uint8List

```
screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
    //Capture Done
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
    });
}).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
});
```

Hence, if you wanna save the image to specific location and share use `captureAndSave` method by passing directory location.

Comment: This example capture only in-app widget, it's possible to capture the whole screen with this plugin ?